# Style of the link text on D3 collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm working on something similar to this collapsible tree with link text: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/82pepd2a/9/, and everything works perfectly in my local environment. However, when I switch to other environment (with Sencha), the style properties of `path` (`stroke`, `fill`, `stroke-width`), which I set on `path.link` propagate to the link text.

Is there a way to specifically set the properties on `path` and `line`, avoiding the effect to the `text`? Or, is it possible to override above properties (I've tried setting `stroke-width` to `1px` and also tried setting above properties to `null`..)? Any other workarounds possible?

I'm not setting CSS directly, but instead using d3. I've tried the below, but it didn't work, obviously:

```
d3.selectAll("path.link path, path.link line").style({
  "fill": "none", 
  "stroke": "#ccc", 
  "stroke-width": "2px"
});
```

Here is the illustration:

Desired:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Comment: maybe it's inheriting some styles??
must add accurate selectors to diference between one and other item?
Without a snippet we cannot try too...

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez yes, that's exactly what's happening... and i'm looking for a way to break this inheritance in this particular siutation.. the difficulty is that it occurs in my production Sencha environment only, so it's hard to reproduce.

Comment: Can you add the inherited properties and values, and your structure in order to find a proper accurate css selector, please?